# PHP - Multiple prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to use 2 prepared statements in the same loop, i tried to take all fields in one query but i cant because of my bbdd model (sometimes first query gives rows and sometimes not, same for second query). Here is the code, i tried to simplify it as much as posible:

```
<?php
if ($db -> rows($sql) > 0) {
    // Prepared SQL1:
    $psql1 = "SELECT user FROM users WHERE ID=?;";
    $prepare_sql1 = $db -> prepare($psql1);
    $prepare_sql1 -> bind_param('i', $topic);

    // Prepared SQL2:
    $psql2 = "SELECT US.ID,
            US.user,
            PT.date,
            PT.time
            FROM posts PT,
            users US
            WHERE ID_topic=?
            AND US.ID = PT.owner
            ORDER BY PT.ID DESC LIMIT 1;";

    $prepare_sql2 = $db -> prepare($psql2);
    $prepare_sql2 -> bind_param('i', $id_topic);

    while ($x = $db -> fetch($sql)) {
        // Prepared SQL1:
        $id_autor_topic = $x['owner'];
        $prepare_sql1 -> execute();
        $prepare_sql1 -> bind_result($autor_topic);
        $prepare_sql1 -> fetch();

        // Prepared SQL2:
        $id_topic = $x['id'];
        $prepare_sql2 -> execute();
        $prepare_sql2 -> bind_result($id, $user, $date, $time);
        $prepare_sql2 -> fetch();
    }

    $prepare_sql1 -> close();
    $prepare_sql2 -> close();
}

?>
```

Both prepared statements works if i only use one, but one i but both only the first works. I searched for a solution and tried lot of things but anything worked, any advice?

Comment: CodeReview would most likely the best place for this if your code is working but needs improving.

Comment: A query in a loop isn't a good idea if you can avoid it, two even worse. What exactly are you doing with these queries though? You're selecting two queries, but you don't use them in the loop?